# Preventing a stressed fish dying. Is it even possible?

Tags: fish

From my personal experience, I never see a stressed fish survive. Usually a stressed fish starts to get weak and then die in several next hours. In my case, it usually happens when I change the water or put some new fishes . Are there any tips?

Comment: For new addition you can add them some time (1hour +) after a feeding with the light closed. I never lost a fish after a waterchange. You do replace the old water with dechlorinated one?

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try it. It's manfish that i'm talking about. It gets reputation for being weak fish.

Comment: What Remi says, turn of light when adding new fish. What temp is your water when you change water?

Comment: I had actually given up for this kind of fish, they kinna need expertise to care them, Now I'm petting stronger fish flower horn and oscar. I'm happy now